# Getting a Namespace Not A function Error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'namespace' bellmedia.videoHub.videoPlayer.js:2
(anonymous function)
```

This is a snippet of my code in the web control

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
             player = BellMedia.videoHub.videoPlayer({
                 destinationCode: globalDestination,
                 platformCode: globalPlatform,
```

And I clicked view source, I did include the bellmedia.videoHub.videoPlaye.js files And this is what it has in line 2 where namespace is definied

```
var BellMedia = BellMedia || {};
BellMedia.namespace('BellMedia.videoHub.videoPlayer');
```

why is it still complaining about the fact that it has no namespace function?

Comment: because if `BellMedia` does not exist it is setting `BellMedia` to an empty object, and objects by default do not have a `namespace` function. Did you include a library that defines `BellMedia` before including the other js script

Comment: var BellMedia = BellMedia || {} that just defines an object, correct?

Comment: it will define an object if BellMedia does not exist, if does exist it just sets it to itself.

Comment: you are correct. the namespace function is not defined. I added it in. that solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this. It turns out the namespace function is missing.